# Django cannot import name from app

Tags: django

Создал проект Django и изменил расположение двух приложений, которые я создал через команду (ниже), в папку applications и файде setting изменил путь к приложению в installed_apps

Код созданя **приложений**

```
python manage.py startapp myapp1
python manage.py startapp myapp2
```

После создания в создал папку (файлы **init**.py присутствуют везду) и переместил в неё два приложения.
**Новая** структура проекта

```
_project
   __applications
      __myapp1
        ...
           models.py
        ...
      __myapp2
        ...
           models.py
        ...
   __project
      __settings.py
      __urls.py

   __manage.py
```

В файле **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'applications.myapp1',
    'applications.myapp2',
]
```

Когда я пытаюсь сделать импорт в файле **myapp1.models**

```
from applications.myapp2.models import SomeModel
```

Я получаю следующею ошибку

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SomeModel' from 'applications.myapp2.models'
```

Подскажите, почему я не могу импортировать ?

Comment: в директории `applications` есть пустой файл `__init__.py`?

Comment: Да. Есть , и в самих myapp тоже

Comment: Попробуйте относительный импорт: `from ...myapp2.models import SomeModel` (с одной точкой искал бы `myapp2.models` внутри `myapp1/models`, с двумя - на уровень выше, в `myapp1`, с тремя - на два уровня выше, в `applications`)

Comment: @insolor нет, не помогло. Не один из вариантов.

Comment: @Jack_oS то есть я не могу в обеих приложения файлах models.py вывести модель из другого приложения. То есть ипортировать в myapp1.models из myapp2.models и сразу же во втором приложении myapp2.models импортировать первую апку

Comment: Только что попробовал воспроизвести, сработало через `from ..myapp2.models import SomeModel2`

Comment: @insolor да это работает. прошу прощения. Но если указать в myapp1 импорта from ..myapp1.models import SomeModel1 будет ошибка.

Comment: Зачем в myapp1.models пытаться что-то импортировать из самого себя? Или где вы это пытаетесь импортировать?

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать так, что бы при создании модели в первом приложении, во втором приложении создавала модель с foreignkey на модель из первой. И когда пользователь в первом приложении делал действия, то во второй моделе(уже другой) делалось запись из модели второго приложения

Comment: Я примерно так и понял. В каком конкретно файле у вас не получается импортировать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124220/discussion-between-wilteratenau-and-insolor).